# How to handle VFS proxy error in WSO2 EI 6.4?

Tags: error-handling, proxy, wso2, vfs

In VFS proxy, How I can handle errors? For example in below cases:

- If VFS is not able to connect to SFTP server due to different reasons(like wrong password, directory not exist etc). I am able to see Warning in console log but I want to send a mail or want to do some other stuff if connection is not possible.
- If the folder does not exist where we have to move file after reading.

I am able to handle error during processing in `FaultSequence` but that thing does not work for proxy. I tried to set `onError` attribute as well but seems proxy does not support that attribute.

Please let me know if someone handle such errors or I am missing something.

```
    <proxy name="FileProxy" startOnLoad="false" statistics="enable" trace="enable" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <target faultSequence="Global_Error_Handler">
            <inSequence>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="status=" value="File received."/>
                </log>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence/>
        </target>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://abc:***@127.0.0.1:22/test/ftp_in?transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:sftp://abc:***@127.0.0.1:22/test/ftp_failure</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName">ReplyFileName.csv</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.dat</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///home/test/ftp_process</parameter>
    </proxy>
```

Need to handle any error that occurs outside the `<target>` functionality of proxy for VFS.