# WSO2 EI - Handle SFTP errors and invoke Fault/error Sequence

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to write a SFTP location through a jms/http proxy. However when there is an error on SFTP endpoint (wrong password, network connectivity issue, remote Dir not exists) I want to trigger fault sequence and handle this error (Try some DLC kind of scenario). I found that fault Sequcence is not invoking for FTP errors unless you set OUT_ONLY=false. However WSO2 docs recommends set OUT_ONLY=true for ftp writes. Similar Question is asked here too. [How to handle VFS proxy error in WSO2 EI 6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799952/how-to-handle-vfs-proxy-error-in-wso2-ei-6-4)

If I set OUT_ONLY=false it triggers faultSquence for both failures and success FTP writes.
Any workaround to catch FTP errors and trigger faultSequence ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a responseAction in the endpoint configuration. Please refer to the following sample configuration. The responseAction spedifies when a response comes to a timed out request specifies whether to discard it or invoke the fault handler. Apart from defining the responseAction in the endpoint, you can replace the send mediator with the file connector and it will also invoke the fault sequence during an error.

```
 <send>
            <endpoint name="wms-fault-endpoint">
               <address uri="vfs:ftp://admin:admin1@localhost:2121/testJ/out">
                  <timeout>
                     <duration>10000</duration>
                     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                  </timeout>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Endpoint+Error+Handling

[2]- https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector