# How to read data from properties file in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2

I created one file `test.properties` in the `//wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/conf` folder.

In this `test.properties` files I created on properties given below

```
testData=welcome
```

Now, I want to read that `testData` value in the proxy files in WSO2.

Here is a proxy code to get the value:

```
<property name="irisprop" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/iris.properties@tokenvalue')" scope="default"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get-property('registry','') will fetch the values stored in the registry [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSmSQ.png). You can refer to the documentation on [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwzFX.png), [3] to further clarification regarding the registry. You can use the carbon console to browse and add the registry resources.
[image]
[image]
You will not be able to read a file content directly with the property mediator. But if your use case is to use the file system to store data, you will need to use the VFS transport or the file connector. Please refer to the documentation [4], [5] to further clarify this.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSmSQ.png)-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Property+Mediator#PropertyMediator-Example4:ReadingafilestoredintheRegistry

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwzFX.png)-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Working+with+the+Registry

[3]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Managing+Registry+Content

[4]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/VFS+Transport

[5]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector

Comment: I am new in wso2 so I don't know much about the registry. I will go through your suggest doc URL but for now, my requirement how to read key-value pairs data from the test.properties file in wso2 proxy. Please suggest any state forwarded solution if any that helps me a lot.

Comment: Hi Shanaka, I created one iris.properties file on the registry using above wso2 management console and I am also able to read that file data. Now I want to find that file iris.properties on my home directory but unable to find this why? please suggest

Comment: WSO2 uses the database to maintain registry artifacts. If you want to find the file that you have created in the registry, you need to browse the registry database, not the file system.

Comment: Hi Any Idea about this Question .I am also facing this issue.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022881/wso2-ei-handle-sftp-errors-and-invoke-fault-error-sequence